# using an alias of a function in a sql condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have something like this:

```
SELECT 
    cansa1.NAME,
    mod(cansa1.PRODUCT_ID, 1000000) prodIdHash
                    
FROM CANSA_TABLE cansa1

INNER JOIN CUSER_TABLE cuser1 ON cansa1.PRODUCT_ID = cuser1.PRODUCT_ID
AND mod(cansa1.PRODUCT_ID, 1000000) = cuser1.PRODUCT_HASH
```

This query is working, but I want replace the second occurrence (in the inner join) of the mod() function, to avoid execute it two times. I tried replace it by the alias in the select clause but not works. Any idea of that I can use to make this query don't repeat the mod() function?

Sorry by my english

Comment: Are you sure mod() is _executed_ twice? Cheap function anyway.

Comment: You may wrap calculation with subquery and then join on the calculated column. Anyway `mod` is not the performance issue in any query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about executing it twice, the SQL engine will optimize the query and will decide whether the function value is cached or it executes twice and can end up re-writing the query so that what is executed has a different structure than the written query because it has determined that it would be more efficient.

If you really want to try to rewrite it then:

```sql
SELECT c.NAME,
       c.prodIdHash
FROM   (
         SELECT name,
                mod(PRODUCT_ID, 1000000) As prodIdHash
         FROM   CANSA_TABLE
       ) c
       INNER JOIN CUSER_TABLE u
       ON (   c.PRODUCT_ID = u.PRODUCT_ID
          AND c.prodIdHash = u.PRODUCT_HASH )
```

However, the SQL engine may rewrite the query and push the function to the outer scope so you may need a seemingly irrelevant filter condition to materialize the inner query and force the calculation not to be rewritten:

```sql
SELECT c.NAME,
       c.prodIdHash
FROM   (
         SELECT name,
                mod(PRODUCT_ID, 1000000) As prodIdHash
         FROM   CANSA_TABLE
         WHERE  ROWNUM > 0
       ) c
       INNER JOIN CUSER_TABLE u
       ON (   c.PRODUCT_ID = u.PRODUCT_ID
          AND c.prodIdHash = u.PRODUCT_HASH )
```

However, this really seems like a case of premature optimisation. You should check if there is actually a problem first before you try and apply an optimisation that probably is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, maybe is an premature optimisation. The query will recover tons of data soon and I want cover all the posibilities to maximize the performance. Anyway is a great answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *derived table* (i.e. a subquery in the `FROM` clause):

```
SELECT dt.NAME, dt.prodIdHash
FROM
  (SELECT 
       cansa1.NAME,
       mod(cansa1.PRODUCT_ID, 1000000) prodIdHash
   FROM CANSA_TABLE cansa1) dt
INNER JOIN CUSER_TABLE cuser1 ON dt.PRODUCT_ID = cuser1.PRODUCT_ID
  AND dt.prodIdHash = cuser1.PRODUCT_HASH
```